# Why would variable "preferredStatusBarStyle" remove the tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller 1 called `main`. When it detects the user hasn't logged in, it presents a view controller 2 called `firstTimeLaunchController`.

The first one (main) is like this:

```
class Main: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if userDefaults?.bool(forKey: "didLogin") != true {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ftController") as! firstTimeLaunchController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the second one, I have a `preferredStatusBarStyle` variable. When it's done, it called dismiss.

```
class firstTimeLaunchController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    ...

    @IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
       ...
       dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

And when it was dismissed, the tab bar of `Main` ViewController disappeared.
It works fine when I deleted this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
}
```

Why would the line about `Status Bar` on ViewController 2 affect the `Tab Bar` on View controller 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with your code, In Info.plist put **View controller-based status bar appearance** as NO